# How to change method implementation in run-time using reflection?

Tags: reflection, go

I have this type implementation:

```
type A struct{
  name string
}

func (a A) getName() string {
  return "My name is " + a.name 
}
```

How I can change implementation of method getName() for this type using reflection?
For example, I want use next implementation instead of current:

```
func newGetName() string {
  return "test reflection"
}
```

Comment: You cannot do this. Such crazy stuff would allow you to change any (exported) method to arbitrary, even harmful stuff. You **must** seek an other way to solve your problem.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Go is a compiled language. As such, it's not possible to modify the implementation of things at runtime. What you can do is changing the place function pointers point to:

```
var getName func(string) = func(name string) {
    return "my name is " + name
}
```

In order to make this work with a structure, you have to resort to a few tricks. First add `getName` as a member to `A`:

```
type A struct {
    name string
    getName func() string
}
```

Then we enclose a pointer to the structure as an implicit (i.e. closed over) parameter:

```
foo := &A{name: "Hans"}
foo.getName = func() string {
    return "my name is " + name
}
```

Now you can call `A.getName()` and the result is `"my name is hans"`. You can use method expressions and many other features just fine, but `getName` is a *structure member* and not a *method* of `A`, so keep this in mind. When you want to give a new meaning to `getName`, assign something different to it:

```
foo.getName = func() string {
    return "test reflection"
}
```

Another idea that is especially applicable if you know in advance what implementations `getName` could have is to add a new member to `A` that says what implementation `getName` currently has and then switch over this variable.

Comment: That seems closer to what the OP was after than in my answer. +1

Answer (score 7):

Note the idiomatic Go is to *not* do that and use interface instead:

See [this example](http://play.golang.org/p/TMkmsaWM0q):

package main

```
import "fmt"

type Aer interface {
    getName() string
}

type A struct {
    name string
}

func (a A) getName() string {
    return "My name is " + a.name
}

type testA struct {
    a A
}

func (ta testA) getName() string {
    return "NEW: My name is " + ta.a.name
}
func main() {
    a := A{name: "nameA"}
    fmt.Println(a.getName())
    ta := testA{a: a}
    fmt.Println(ta.getName())
}
```

Output:

```
My name is nameA
NEW: My name is nameA
```

Comment: I cannot change this line:

    fmt.Println(a.getName())

I need other solution

Comment: Exactly! You cannot change it. Neither did I. Which is why I wrapped your object in an interface.

Comment: You use "ta" instead of "a" for call new method. I can not do this replacement.

Comment: @Interloper your method is not exported anyway, which means I doubt you could call it by reflection.

Comment: Can I change the pointer to the implementation of the method?

Comment: Not that I know, no, for the same reason mentioned by Volker

Comment: It looks like there are some tricks to be done with `unsafe` and `reflct.MakeFunc()` that just might work, but apart from the challenge in it, this really is not anything anyone should do in real life.